# How to ignore files from TortoiseSVN without deleting them?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Assuming someone accidentially checked in a config file or if there are build folders in my repository, how can I remove/ignore them from SVN without deleting the files for all users with their next update?

Lets say I update a root folder's properties to ignore the file config.xml. If I try to commit my changes the next time, it will commit the new properties for the root folder but also mark config.xml as deleted. And this doesn't seem correct because now everyone's config.xml will be deleted with their next svn update although I just want the file to be dropped and ignored from SVN.
I've tried doging the delete for everyone by only commiting the folder property change and not the "delete action" but now I've got weird tree conflicts and all in all it looks like there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot ignore files that are inside the Subversion repository. You can only ignore non-existent files or directories.

If I understand you correctly, there is currently a file called `config.xml` inside the repository. If you delete this from the repository, it will be deleted when other users do an `svn update`. Sad, but true.

However, if that happens, it meant that the user's local copy was an exact duplicate of the older version. No problem, they simply just have to run `svn cat` the `config.xml` file to that revision, and they'll have it back.

What if they've modified the `config.xml` file? They'll get the following error on update:

```
Tree conflict on 'config.xml'
    > local file edit, incoming file delete upon update
    Select: (r) mark resolved, (p) postpone, (q) quit resolution, (h) help:
```

They should postpone the resolution. Then:

```
$ svn delete --keep-local config.xml
```

This will keep their local version of `config.xml` and resolve the conflict.

If they marked the conflict as *resolved*, Subversion will mark `config.xml` to be added to the repository.

To prevent that, you can use my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) which you can configure to cause a commit to fail if someone tries to add in this particular file.

Answer (score 7):

In commit or "check for modifications dialog" you can right click on the files you want to ignore and choose via **"add to ignore list"** either ignore **"this.file"** or ignore **"*.file"** ("file" may be your suffix).
Note that SVN stores your ignored files in a so-called "property" in the directory the file exists. So the directoy will show up as changed.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

With TortoiseSVN: right click on file, TortoiseSVN -> "Unversion and add to ignore list" then select the file name / wildcard /etc.

[Ignore files which are already versioned](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion.html)

> If you accidentally added some files which should have been ignored, how do you get them out of version control without losing them? Maybe you have your own IDE configuration file which is not part of the project, but which took you a long time to set up just the way you like it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found as well but was afraid by the files being marked as 'deleted'. But it's not a 'delete' which actually deletes the file on other user's file systems but only deletes the file from the repository and marks it as being deleted.
That said, every time I commit new changes now it will still list all the delete/ignored files as if they were changed (status still deleted). That's somewhat annoying. I guess I could put all of them on the ignore-on-commit list but ideally they'd just show up as unversioned files now...

Comment: Actually it works this way! The problem was that someone of my team checked in build files, I then compiled the project for my machine, overwrote the build files and then it got problems when my files where newer, not committed but I still tried to mark them as to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If like me you somehow added files that were not intended for subversion you just make backup copies of the relevant files. svn remove 'thefile'. Commit to repo and then change the names of the backup files to the originals. Good for a handful of files at least.